# Monitoring network activity in an HTML5 iphone/android app?

Tags: android, iphone, html

I want to create an HTML5 app for iPhones and Androids that is based on an HTML5 app framework. The app will do nothing but monitor the network activity (only cellular not WIFI) of the device.

I have been searching for how to do this for a few hours now, but haven't been able to find out how to do this, or even if it is possible or not.

**Is it possible to monitor iPhones/Androids network activity in an HTML5 app built on an HTML5 app framework? And if so, how?**

(I'd prefer to find a framework that exposes the network data usage of iPhones and Androids to the app instead of coding my own if possible)

Comment: Hi Tim, I've made some edits to your question in an attempt to get it reopened. If I've changed your question too much, feel free to [edit] it further or roll back my changes :)

Comment: Based on the edits, I've re-opened it (it's no longer a 'shopping list' question).  Whether it gets re-closed/deleted is up to the community.

Answer (score 1):

If you built the application container for your HTML5 app then yes with the new Web Inspector for Safari, this works as well if your building a mobile html5 app on a server.

Chrome also has a similar debugging feature for Android.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging